# How do I implement form based login with mysql in a RESTful web service?

Tags: web-services, rest

I am developing hybrid mobile Application using phonegap(jquery mobile framework) and jersey rest java webservice.

How to do login and logout using mysql and rest webservice and maintain session of perticular user on every page like traditional webapplication(get username on every page).

i am totally stuck.can anyone provide sample example or any solution.

Comment: so what have you tried so far? In my little knowledge I would maintain a flag in backend , which at the time of login will be 1 and at the time of logout has be set to 0. Before login this flag is checked, if set to 1 , that means the user is logged so his prefs are retrieved , and if 0 , that means a clean session should start with login process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do in below way.

create session table contains column [id, token, userid, loggedintime]

on login call a rest like `/rest/user/login?username=uname&password=pwd`
which return a token to user. maintain that token at client side. you may use cookie or sessionstorage whichever supported by mobile device.

now create one Filter with `path /*` so each request pass through it, and in filter check that the users token is valid or not, if not than redirect to login. you can explicitly  pass that token to server in `queryparam` or `pathparam`.

on logout delete entry from session table, and redirect user to login page again.

there are many way to do this thing but this is a simpler way.

Comment: "create session table" at this point you violated the stateless constraint of REST.

Comment: right @inf3rno, but its clearly mentioned on question that he want to do such thing using mysql.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, you store the username and password in your client and send them with every request. (On the server side you can have an `(username, password) -> (identity, permissions)` in-memory cache which can make things faster.) You need a secure connection: HTTPS. Without that you won't do REST auth.

Login is simple you show a prompt to the user, in which she can give the username and password, so you can store them in the memory of the client. By logout you can simply close the client (by browsers navigate away), or remove the username and password from the memory of it. (It is not secure to permanently store the username and password without proper encryption on the client side.)